# Mixed Arabic and English usage in a HTML page

Tags: css, arabic

I have this piece of code:

```
<td class="test">
  <a href="/bar">هىفشتهو</a>
  ⋅
  <a class="text-muted" href="/bar">1 week ago</a>
</td>
```

The above code looks at the page as it shown on the screenshot:

[image: PIC]

As you can see it has mixed English and Arabic texts. Is there a technique to solve browser's behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding additional HTML code. I use Bootstrap so the class `list-inline` is from there.

```
<ul class="list-inline">
 <li><a href="/bar">هىفشتهو</a></li>
 <li>⋅</li>
 <li><a class="text-muted" href="/bar">1 week ago</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now it looks normal:

[image]